# How to keep state in reactPHP server?

Tags: php, reactphp

ReachPHP server. Code for counting the number of requests:

```
$counter = 0;

$app = function ($request, $response) use ($counter){        
    $response->writeHead(200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
    $response->end($counter);
    $counter++;
};

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$http = new React\Http\Server($socket, $loop);

$http->on('request', $app);
echo "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337\n";

$socket->listen(1337);
$loop->run();
```

The counter remains 0 for every request, how can I make $counter variable persistent for all requests to the server ?

Comment: I don't see anything that would change `$counter`. If the code that modifes `$counter` is not included here, could you please post it in an edit.

Comment: yes i missed $counter++;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to put &-sign before $counter to transfer by reference:

```
$counter = 0;

$app = function ($request, $response) use (&$counter){        
    $response->writeHead(200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
    $response->end($counter);
    $counter++;
};

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$http = new React\Http\Server($socket, $loop);

$http->on('request', $app);
echo "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337\n";

$socket->listen(1337);
$loop->run();
```

silly me...